# Область видимости и private метод

Tags: php, ооп

Разбираюсь с областью видимости методов и свойств классов. Казалось, что в теме разобрался, но есть недопонимание одного момента. Вот простой кусок кода с комментами:

```
<?php

class Base {
    public function test() {
        $this->testPrivate();
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Base::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

class SubBase extends Base {    
    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "SubBase::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

$obj = new SubBase();
echo $obj->test(); // Почему результат: Base::testPrivate?
```

В данном конкретном примере `$this` указывает на экземпляр класса `SubBase`, поэтому эта запись равносильна примерно следующему: `SubBase:: testPrivate();`
Понятно, что мы вызываем этот метод все-таки из класса `Base` и не можем получить доступ к приватному методу `SubBase`. Тогда по логике вещей должны получить ошибку, но почему же в этом случае подтягивается приватный метод родительского класса `Base`? Или это такая логика: если не могу получить метод из дочернего класса, то получаю его из родительского?

Comment: Суть, собственно, в том, что приватные методы не доступны в дочерних классах (_и наоборот_) и переопределение их так же невозможно. Поэтому `$this->testPrivate();` всегда будет смотреть на метод в своём классе.

Answer (score 1):

потому что test() публичный ключ имеет
и потому через неё и получаем доступ - см.инкапсуляция. Как геттеры и сеттеры. Напрямую обратиться не можешь, а через посредника - пожалуйста. PS и суперкласс в приоритете исполнения.

Comment: я бы на вашем месте еще раз внимательно перечитал код в вопросе